# JPA Query with DateTime difference

Tags: function, datetime, jpa, querydsl

I would like to know if there is a nice way to make a JPA Query with a clause on a difference between DataTime colums beeing greater or lower than a constant (or even more another third column).

It seems so simple in Native SQL.

Example in Oracle : select date1, date2, date2 - date1 as delta from my_table where date2 - date1 > interval ´4´ hour ;

I am using QueryDSL JPA, but I guess that if JPA is enable to manage it, then QueryDSL JPA should also.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: why not post how YOU would do it with SQL, and then people can answer how to do that in JPQL ...

Comment: Exemple in Oracle SQL : select date1, date2, date2 - date1 as delta from my_table where date2 - date1 > interval ´4´ hour ;

Comment: Most JPA providers support an "HOUR" function (in JPQL).